# Copying XSL Feed from one URL to another URL

Tags: php, rss, feed

There is an RSS feed:

```
www.domain1.com/rss.xsl
```

I need to copy this xsl feed to another webhost to make

```
www.domain2.com/rsscopy.xsl
```

How can I do this? Can I do it via PHP?

Thanks :)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` functions.

```
<?php

$rss = file_get_contents('http://www.domain1.com/rss.xsl');

$filename = 'rssCopy.xsl';
$saveRss = file_put_contents($filename, $rss);

if($saveRss)
{
    echo 'RSS Copied';
}
```

Save the above script in your `domain2.com` and call it via URL.

Comment: @wigglyredlines Please accept my answer if you found it useful.